# Como usar o valor do SelectedValue do DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Seguinte, tenho uma tabela "animais" com campo "sexo" (varchar(1)). Nele eu seto M ou F, para Macho ou Fêmea.

Uso detailsView pra mostrar/editar esses campos e gostaria de ter um DropDownList no EditTemplate com as opções Macho ou Fêmea e ao clicar em editar, atualizar no banco de dados com M ou F.

Como faço?

Meu código:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sexo:" SortExpression="sexo">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="sexoDrop" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="M">Macho</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="F">Fêmea</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sexo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sexo") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<UpdateParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter Name="sexo" ControlID="sexoDrop" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</UpdateParameters>

UpdateCommand="UPDATE [animais] SET [sexo] = @sexo WHERE [id] = @original_id"
```

Answer (score 3):

Supondo que seu DropDownList se chame 'ddlSexo', para obter o valor use:

```
string sexo = ddlSexo.SelectedValue;
```

E para popular o DropDownList, supondo que você está lendo de um DataTable de nome 'dt' e que tenha uma coluna de nome 'sexo', use:

```
ddlSexo.DataSource = dt;
ddlSexo.DataTextField = "sexo";
ddlSexo.DataValueField = "sexo";
ddlSexo.DataBind();
```

Comment: No caso eu uso o SQLDataSource, existe alguma maneira usando ele?

Answer (score 2):

Da maneira que nosso amigo @Daniel Manfrini citou está correta:

> Supondo que seu DropDownList se chame 'ddlSexo', para obter o valor
>   use:
>
> string sexo = ddlSexo.SelectedValue;
>
> E para popular o DropDownList, supondo que você está lendo de um
>   DataTable de nome 'dt' e que tenha uma coluna de nome 'sexo', use:
>
> ddlSexo.DataSource = dt;
>
> ddlSexo.DataTextField = "sexo";
>
> ddlSexo.DataValueField = "sexo";
>
> ddlSexo.DataBind();

porém você pode criar um campo char que guarde a sigla do Sexo no banco e atribuir o texto de Exibição como 'Macho' e o valor oculto que deve ser realmente utilizado vc atribui o campo Sigla ('M' ou 'F').

Aí ficaria assim:

`ddlSexo.DataSource = dt;
 ddlSexo.DataTextField = "sexo"; //Nome do campo que tem a descricao completa ex.: Macho ou Femea 
 ddlSexo.DataValueField = "sigla"; //Nome do campo que guarda o valor da Sigla usada para aquela descricao
 ddlSexo.DataBind();`

E ao pegar o valor no code-behind já pegaria a sigla que vai usar no banco.
`string siglaSexo = ddlSexo.SelectedValue;`

Answer (score 1):

Para atualizar no banco a cada vez que tu modifica a seleção, é necessário capturar o evento SelectedIndexChanged e dentro do mesmo adicionar uma lógica que conecte no banco de dados e faça a atualização. Adicione no teu dropdownlist o atributo: `OnSelectedIndexChanged="sexoDrop_SelectedIndexChanged"`
e no code-behind adicione o método:

```
protected void sexoDrop_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //CódigoVaiAqui.
    }
```

Lembrando que como tu esta usando um detailsView, para acessar o DropDownList, é necessário procurar o mesmo dentro do detailsview, já que ele não é acessível diretamente pelo code-behind. Exemplo:

```
DropDownList ddlSexo = detailsViewID.FindControl("sexoDrop") as DropDownList;
```