# DropDownList não funciona dentro de DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dropdown

Tenho um `DetailsView` com vários campos e um `DropDownList` que deve atualizar o campo `sexoAnimal` com Macho (M) ou Fêmea (F).

Adicionei um `ControlParameter` no `SqlDataSource`, o parâmetro pega o valor selecionado no `DropDown`.

Se eu deixo o `DropDownList` dentro do `DetailsView`, ele dá esse erro:

> Não foi possível encontrar o controle 'sexoDrop' em ControlParameter 'sexoC'.

Se eu tiro ele pra fora do `DetailsView` (exemplo: em baixo), ele atualiza o campo `Sexo` normalmente.

O que posso/devo fazer para funcionar dentro do `DetailsView`?

Cód DropDown:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="sexoDrop" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="M">Macho</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="F">Fêmea</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Parâmetro:

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="sexoC" ControlID="sexoDrop" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
```

Comment: Poderia postar um trecho maior de código do seu APSX e tbm do seu source ASPX.cs q faz a chamada dos métodos?

Comment: @tchicotti, está tudo sendo feito no .aspx, usando os componentes DetailsView com SqlDataSource.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme eu respondi na tua outra pergunta: [Como usar o valor do SelectedValue do DropDownList?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8585/como-usar-o-valor-do-selectedvalue-do-dropdownlist/9289#9289)
Uma forma de fazer isso é recebendo o DropDownList do DetailsView e fazendo a lógica de update dentro do code-behind. Nunca utilizei o SqlDataSource, mas pelo erro que está dando o problema é que o DropDownList não esta acessível para o SqlDataSource.
Da mesma forma que no code-behind é necessário realizar um dvId.FindControl("sexoDrop"), será necessário realizar o mesmo no SqlDataSource. Agora como fazer isso eu não sei, pois nunca utilizei este controle.